# Create a standalone HTML from charts with a layout

Tags: python, html, bokeh

I want to create a standalone HTML contained several interactive graphs (if possible) with Bokeh based on a layout.

I have successfully created each chart as its own HTML or PNG.

My graphs are generated individually from functions. Here's an example.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

def create_scatter():
    # output to static HTML file
    output_file("test_scatter.html")
    p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title='This is a Scatter chart')

    # add a circle renderer with a size, color, and alpha
    p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
    p.title.text_font_style = "italic"

    # show the results
    show(p)

    # Attemp to return the chart
    return p


def create_line():
    # output to static HTML file
    output_file("line.html")
    p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title='This is a Line chart')

    # add a line renderer
    p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=2)
    p.title.text_color = "olive"
    p.toolbar.logo = None # Hide Bokeh Logo

    # show the results
    show(p)

    # Attemp to return the chart
    return p


def create_HTML(f1, f2):
    pass


def main():
    f1 = create_scatter()
    f2 = create_line()
    create_HTML(f1, f2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, I could not find a way to put them all together in one HTML file. Each chart has its own unique title, attributes, legend, and tools.

My expected result is to create a standalone HTML based on a layout, possibly can be modified its background, etc. Here's my expected outcome.

[image: layout]

Thank you in advance

**Update**

I presume I need to return components of a graph

```
script, div = components(p, CDN)
return script, div
```

Then I need to put them into HTML strings. Finally, output the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already gave yourself the answer. Using `components` is one way to realize it.
Please check the [Bokeh embed](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/embed.html) documentation for all options.

If you want a single file implementation that you could use this approach (tested with Bokeh 1.1.0):

```
from jinja2 import Template
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.models import Div, Paragraph, Row, Column
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.util.browser import view

template = Template("""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{ title if title else "Bokeh Plot" }}</title>
        {{ bokeh_css | safe }}
        {{ bokeh_js | safe }}
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ plot_div | safe }}
        {{ plot_script | safe }}
    </body>
</html> """)

p1 = figure(plot_width = 400, plot_height = 400)
p2 = figure(plot_width = 400, plot_height = 400)
p3 = figure(plot_width = 800, plot_height = 400)
p1.circle([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
p2.line([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
p3.line([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

html = file_html(Column(Row(p1, p2), Row(p3)), template = template, resources = CDN)

output_file = 'css_classes.html'
with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
view(output_file)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a further question, is this possible to change its background, and make it responsive?

Comment: Update: I added <body style="background-color:powderblue;">, it works fine. I am currently looking for a way to make it responsive.